# Locale on django and uwsgi UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, django, localization, uwsgi

EDIT: I just realized, that when i'm not trying to print to console that variable, it works. Why?

I run into an issue related to displaying string label with utf chars. I set locale env in uwsgi ini file like this:

```
env =LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
env =LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and in wsgi.py:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

When I run app code:

```
print (locale.getlocale(), locale.getpreferredencoding())
print locale.getdefaultlocale()
print "option_value", option_value
label = force_text(option_label)
print 'label', label #THIS FAILS
```

the output is:

```
(('en_US', 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8')
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
option_value d
ERROR <stack trace>
print 'label', label
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u015b' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The problem is not present when I run app via runserver in production environment.
Django 1.6.5 Python 2.7.6 Ubuntu 14.04 uWSGI 2.0.5.1

Comment: is the error for this command ? `print "option_value", option_value`

Comment: print 'label', label fails (edited)

Comment: do the answer pls ! ans say the result !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found answer here: http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2014/01/12/python-unicode-console-output.html

Realized that the console is responsible for that error, so exporting additional env variable in uwsgi config file solves the issue: `env = PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`

Comment: In case of using uwsgi from command line without config, add `--env=PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

for all in django when you want use unicode , like in forms and etc .. you must set a `u` in leading of your unicode that you want to be saved ! do this any where that your unicode have been saved !
in this case i think it is `(option_label)`

Comment: value of label variable fails, not string 'label'

Comment: did you try this actually:`print u'label', label` ?

Comment: print u'label', label
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u015b' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: so because the `lable` is  `'option_value'` for all in django when you want use uni code like in forms and etc .. you must set a `u` in leading of your unicode that you want to be saved ! do this any where that your unicode have been saved !